# My code doesn't have any error but mysqli_num_rows give zero value

Tags: php, html, web, authentication, backend

I made a login script in PHP, and the process needs to check whether data from login form is match with data in my table. I use mysqli_num_rows to do that. But it gives zero value. How can I fix this?

I have no idea but I've already tried a method with mysqli_fetch_array and the result is still same.

Edit : Table app_user has id_level, and id_level is a foreign key. Is there could be a problem in the database? But I'm not using id_level in the login process. Or it could be a xampp server error?

```
include "lib/conn.php";

$data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM app_user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
echo "<pre>".print_r($data, true)."</pre>";

if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0){
    $_SESSION['error'] = '<strong>ERROR!</strong> username atau password salah.';
    //header('Location:login.php');
    echo "x";
    die();
}
```

So, I want mysqli_num_rows to give me 1, but the existing output is 0.

Comment: you can try this if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){

Comment: From what I could gather, this SQL query is simpy returning no rows from the database. Maybe there's some gutter in the variables $user or $pass?

Comment: Can you echo the query with values & run it directly on the DB. So that you can confirm there is a output. Sometimes password field might be encoded in the DB.

Comment: @MohammadMalek I've already tried it but it still same.

Comment: try it to echo last_query

Comment: Did you tried SELECT * FROM your_schema_name.app_user... ?

Comment: @Leandragem $user and $pass already have data in there.

Comment: What was the result & what was the response when you directly run that in DB.?

Comment: @Sinto Yes, there's data there. The query worked successfully in DB but not in my script.

Comment: Confirm that the connected DB is correct & please remove the `print_r()` section from the code.

Comment: var_dump($data) check if the table record coming or not..